# Not able to connect to the translation API

Tags: python-2.7, azure

url: https://translatorappeagle.cognitiveservices.azure.com/
I'm also using my key from my resources page. I get a an error 404: not found. I copied the code from the getting started section for the translation API.
Please let me know what to do.

```
import os, requests, uuid, json


key_var_name = 'TRANSLATOR_TEXT_SUBSCRIPTION_KEY'

if not key_var_name in os.environ:

    raise Exception('Please set/export the environment variable: {}'.format(key_var_name))

subscription_key = os.environ[key_var_name]



endpoint_var_name = 'TRANSLATOR_TEXT_ENDPOINT'

if not endpoint_var_name in os.environ:

    raise Exception('Please set/export the environment variable: {}'.format(endpoint_var_name))

endpoint = os.environ[endpoint_var_name]

# If you encounter any issues with the base_url or path, make sure

# that you are using the latest endpoint: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cognitive-services/translator/reference/v3-0-translate

path = '/translate?api-version=3.0'

params = '&to=de&to=it'

constructed_url = endpoint + path + params



headers = {

    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': subscription_key,

    'Content-type': 'application/json',

    'X-ClientTraceId': str(uuid.uuid4())

}



# You can pass more than one object in body.

body = [{

    'text' : 'Hello World!'

}]

request = requests.post(constructed_url, headers=headers, json=body)

response = request.json()

print(json.dumps(response, sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',', ': ')))
```

Comment: use "https://api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com/translate" as `endpoint` and see if it works. (you can set `TRANSLATOR_TEXT_ENDPOINT` environment variable to the url)

Comment: "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: Sorry, remove the "/translate" part from the url I've sent you. Set it again. (Only 'api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com')